# pyodbc: query results to CSV?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to access a database and print the query results.

How do I use pyodbc to print the whole query result including the columns to a csv file?

CODE:

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    #DATA BASE NAME IS HERE, HID FOR PRIVACY  )


cursor  = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute(""" #COMMAND GOES HERE """)


row = cursor.fetchall() #FETCHES ALL ROWS

cnxn.commit() 
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: This is obviously subjective but I do this using pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> How do I use pyodbc to print the whole query result including the columns to a csv file?

You don't use pyodbc to "print" anything, but you can use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to dump the results of a pyodbc query to CSV.

As a minimal example, this works for me:

```python
import csv
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=myDb")
crsr = conn.cursor()
# test data
sql = """\
SELECT 1 AS id, 'John Glenn' AS astronaut
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS id, 'Edwin "Buzz" Aldrin' AS astronaut
"""
rows = crsr.execute(sql)
with open(r'C:\Users\gord\Desktop\astro.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow([x[0] for x in crsr.description])  # column headers
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

producing a CSV file containing

```
id,astronaut
1,John Glenn
2,"Edwin ""Buzz"" Aldrin"
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense, that I have to use the csv module.

Comment: You can dump all results to the csv file without looping:

`writer.writerows(rows)`

Comment: Wouldn't that fit the entire result set in memory, @MilovanTomašević? I think the purpose of the loop is to avoid that.

Comment: I don't know which part of the answer is not clear to you, if you look at the code you will see that the loop is used there properly, as a suggestion it is written if he wants to enter the whole result at once given a suggestion without a loop.  So the user chooses what suits him in which case.  For that reason, your comment is completely superfluous to me.

Answer (score 4):

Improving billmanH's answer:

```py
conn = pyodbc.connect(' ... ')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT ...')

col_headers = [ i[0] for i in cursor.description ]
rows = [ list(i) for i in cursor.fetchall()] 
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=col_headers)

df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: fetch all the rows in the memory it's a very bad idea

Comment: @BenyGj Yeah, this is not intended for large amounts of data.

Answer (score 4):

You can export your select result to a CSV file with this.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc 

conn = pyodbc.connect('""" Connection String """')

df = pd.read_sql_query('""" Select Query """', conn)
df.to_csv('""" CSV file path """', index=False)
```