# Get the column names of a query from pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Is there a way to get the column names of a query result at run time?

I am trying to see if there is a generic approach to run a query, capture the results and send the results in an email using pyodbc

Comment: The answer I was looking for was something similar to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844895/pyodbc-query-results-to-csv

Answer (score 4):

The cursor-object has a `description`-attribute that [does what you ask for](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

for your current row

```
str(cursor.description[0][0])
```

cursor.description contains the data you need with the first tuple, but it is the first string inside the first indice that you need.